# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$ (where $\gamma$ is a primitive 5-th root of unity) is a splitting field for $x^5-1$

Tags: galois-theory

I know that my roots are going to be $\{1, \gamma, \gamma^2, \gamma^3, \gamma^4 \}$.  I have to show that these are unique roots of the polynomial.  In this problem I have to consider the polynomial $\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$.  Basically I know that this is identical to $x^4+x^3+...+x+1$, so I know that if I plug in $\gamma$ I will get that $\gamma^4$ is a linear combination of the other roots, and I have to make a contradiction argument to show that the others are unique roots.  Then I must somehow show that $\gamma^4$ is also a root.

I'm really stuck.

Comment: If we go to complex numbers, we know that the roots of $x^5-1$ are the powers of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi$ be a primitive $5$-th root of unity - this means that $\xi$ is a complex number whose multiplicative order in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is $5$. Then $\xi^{5} = 1$, and $\xi$ generates a cyclic group of order $5$ inside $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Note $\langle \xi \rangle = \{1, \xi, \xi^{2}, \xi^{3}, \xi^{4}\}$, so each of these elements are distinct. By Lagrange, every nonidentity element of $\langle \xi \rangle$ has order $5$, so these elements are the $5$ distinct roots of $P(X) = X^{5} - 1$. Hence, the splitting field for $P(X)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(1, \xi, \xi^{2}, \xi^{3}, \xi^{4}) = \mathbb{Q}(\xi)$.